# Batch script to delete all the lines from the line that starts with a specific word "TRAIL"

Tags: batch-file

I want to write a Batch script for the first time and am struck.

The requirement is: 
I want to delete all the lines in a text file that comes after the line that starts with the letters "TRAI......".

Example:
My test file looks like:

```
123 sdefef dhufheij 123232
234 ddefef mijijijj 232323
345        jcdhence 345987
TRAILER0000034
456 edrftg nbuyfjjf 678655
```

Result should be:

```
123 sdefef dhufheij 123232
234 ddefef mijijijj 232323
345        jcdhence 345987
456 edrftg nbuyfjjf 678655
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>This can be easily done with sed to find a pattern</strike>

```
sed -i 's/TRAI.*//' your_file.txt
```

The -i flag modifies the actual file. "s/TRAI.*//" finds a pattern starting with TRAI and everything that follows (represented by .*) and replaces it with nothing

Edit: Nevermind, I misread "batch script" as "bash script"

Answer (score 0):

The `findstr` utility can be used to filter lines.  I'll leave the rest of the logic up to you.